# How should I handle the starting and stopping of BlueStacks from VB code?

Tags: vb.net, bluestacks

I have a VB application that I'm using to automate tasks with BlueStacks. This requires me to be able to exit BlueStacks completely and restart it within my code.

So I have two questions:

1. Right now I'm looking looking up all BlueStacks processes by name and calling `process.Kill()`. The process will be restarted and killed many times over an extended period of time. Is there any downside to this?
2. If there is a downside, is there some way I can tell BlueStacks to close itself without just killing it's process?

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

try this in killing the all processes that is needed to be killed.. I've ask the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30820710/kill-process-end-process-of-bluestacks/30881107#30881107) and arrive to such answer

```
        Dim KillProcess As New Process
    Dim KillStartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
    Dim KillProcessName(3) As String
    KillProcessName(0) = "/c taskkill /IM HD-BlockDevice.exe /f"
    KillProcessName(1) = "/c taskkill /IM HD-Agent.exe /f"
    KillProcessName(2) = "/c taskkill /IM HD-LogRotatorService.exe /f"
    KillProcessName(3) = "/c taskkill /IM HD-UpdaterService.exe /f"

    For i = 0 To 3 Step 1
        With KillStartInfo
            .Arguments = KillProcessName(i)
            .CreateNoWindow = True
            .UseShellExecute = False
            KillProcess.StartInfo = KillStartInfo
            KillProcess.Start()
            KillProcess.WaitForExit()
        End With

    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

*I've never used BlueStacks.

Regarding #1 - Yes...and no; we don't know.  Process.Kill() terminates with extreme prejudice, not allowing the app to properly shutdown and possibly cleanup its resources correctly.  Is this actually happening?...we don't know.  Different apps will respond, well, differently...it just depends on how they were written under the hood.  It's always possible that using Kill() will have no adverse affects at all.  The opposite could be true, too.

Regarding #2 - If the app has a User Interface, then [Process.CloseMainWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the preferred method to shut it down.  This will send a WM_CLOSE message to the main window which in theory should allow most apps to properly shutdown and cleanup their resources.  If Process.CloseMainWindow() doesn't work for your situation, then you're stuck with Process.Kill().

Comment: Thanks for your response. After trying `Process.CloseMainWindow()`, it appears it works to an extent. BlueStacks is running two processes, one for the interface and another that leaves an icon in the notification area on the task bar. It does terminate the one process. This may be good enough, but I will need to play around longer before I know for sure. Thanks again for your answer.